# Dropdown bootstrap menu with unfold effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make the bootstrap menu dropdown on hover with an unfold effect.

Right now I have this javascript to make it dropdown on hover with a slide effect:

```
// dropdown hover effect
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp()
});
```

this works well on desktop version but not on mobile and doesn't have the unfold effect.

What's the best way to achieve this? Via javascript or css?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/htya5d3n/) for a mobile-friendly CSS solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right on desktop the code works well as desktop version supports hover event but mobile version does not. Mobile version should be handled using click event.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the effect like this:

```
// dropdown hover effect
if($(window).width() > 768) {
  $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('open');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
  });
};
```

and css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s;
      transition: all 0.5s;

      max-height: 0;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(-90deg); 
        -moz-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(-90deg); 
        transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(-90deg);
    }

    .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
      max-height: 250px;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(0deg); 
        -moz-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(0deg); 
        transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(0deg);
        transform-origin: center top;
    }
}
```

the `max-height` will depend on how many buttons you have in the dropdown, the more you have, the more height.

Comment: remember you cannot use hover events with touch screen mobile devices